# Edit Text Matlab Gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm writing a Gui with Guide. I have an Edit text box in it. Is it possible to write a vector  instead of a single value in this box?

Comment: You can put anything you want in it as long as it's a string...

Comment: I wish I could do something like that: [0.5 0.4 0.1].
Is it possibile in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, as I said you have to convert to a string, using, for example, `num2str([0.5 0.4 0.1])`.

Comment: I did something like that:
handles.weights=str2double(get(handles.w, 'String'))

Comment: handles.array=inVdati;
    handles.weights=get(handles.w, 'String');
    w=num2str(handles.weights);
    port_ret=handles.array*w';
    handles.port = port_ret;

Is it right in your opinion?